# Hyperlink from attribute table gets send to browser missing the last character, }

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, hyperlink

I am using QGIS 3.10.2-A. I'm working with city data and parcels. I populated my attribute table with a lengthy hyperlink that ends in `}`. The string is about 455 characters, and it shows in the attribute table complete. However, when clicked, it gets sent to the browser (Firefox, Chrome or Internet Explorer) missing the last `}`. It renders the hyperlink useless.

- I imported the hyperlink to QGIS from a CSV form (no problem)
- The details side panel shows it complete When the hyperlink gets clicked,    prompts to an error page I tried cntrl+c/v and still misses the last character.
- I can manually add the } to the URL and the URL works fine then.
- Other hyperlinks work fine as long as they don't end in }
- No actions from action-menu were added or needed with working    hyperlinks.
- hyperlink shown in attribute table

[image: hyperlink]

```
https://www.zillow.com/tx/?searchQueryState={%22pagination%22:{},%22usersSearchTerm%22:%22texas%22,%22mapBounds%22:{%22west%22:-98.7578398,%22east%22:-98.7547018,%22south%22:29.79359607,%22north%22:29.79556007},%22regionSelection%22:[{%22regionId%22:54,%22regionType%22:2}],%22isMapVisible%22:true,%22mapZoom%22:18,%22filterState%22:{%22sortSelection%22:{%22value%22:%22globalrelevanceex%22},%22isAllHomes%22:{%22value%22:true}},%22isListVisible%22:true}
```

Hyperlink sent to browser

```
https://www.zillow.com/tx/?searchQueryState={%22pagination%22:{},%22usersSearchTerm%22:%22texas%22,%22mapBounds%22:{%22west%22:-98.7578398,%22east%22:-98.7547018,%22south%22:29.79359607,%22north%22:29.79556007},%22regionSelection%22:[{%22regionId%22:54,%22regionType%22:2}],%22isMapVisible%22:true,%22mapZoom%22:18,%22filterState%22:{%22sortSelection%22:{%22value%22:%22globalrelevanceex%22},%22isAllHomes%22:{%22value%22:true}},%22isListVisible%22:true
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `}` and `{` are an unsafe characters in a URL and should only be included in a URL if they are URL encoded.

`{` becomes `%7B` and `}`becomes `%7D`

The URL you should store is:

```
https://www.zillow.com/tx/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22:%7B%7D,%22usersSearchTerm%22:%22texas%22,%22mapBounds%22:%7B%22west%22:-98.7578398,%22east%22:-98.7547018,%22south%22:29.79359607,%22north%22:29.79556007%7D,%22regionSelection%22:[%7B%22regionId%22:54,%22regionType%22:2%7D],%22isMapVisible%22:true,%22mapZoom%22:18,%22filterState%22:%7B%22sortSelection%22:%7B%22value%22:%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D,%22isAllHomes%22:%7B%22value%22:true%7D%7D,%22isListVisible%22:true%7D
```

For further details see for example:

[(Please) Stop Using Unsafe Characters in URLs](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)

Comment: Awesome. That did it. thank you!